# Perl Compile Error - make: [pod/perltoc.pod] Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, perl, compilation, nas, qnap

I have a Qnap NAS TS-119 PII with an ARM processor.
I need a newer Perl version as ipkg offers.
I want to install Perl from the source.
The Configure command works great:

```
 ./Configure -Dcc=gcc -Dprefix=/custom/lib/perl -des -Dusethreads
```

I get an error when I do a

```
make
```

Error:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/share/HDA_DATA/custom/temp/perl-5.18.0/dist/threads-shared'
./perl -f -Ilib pod/buildtoc -q
make: *** [pod/perltoc.pod] Segmentation fault
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: `Can someone help me please?`  With the amount of information provided, seems unlikely.

Comment: What information do you need?
Can I produce a debug or something like this?

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is trying it without threads.  If that works, then there's a starting point for debugging.  After that, you should [report this as a bug to perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlbug.html).

Comment: Thank you for advise. I get the same eroor without -Dusethreads.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread, with some good links: http://forum.subsonic.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6459&start=15

Like this: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/perl-compilation-failing-no-error-definitions-found-at-errno_pm-pl-922506/

Regards,